# Setting up BindingContext for XML Fragment

Tags: xml, data-binding, sapui5

I have an XML fragment called from another view.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified">

    <u:Menu itemSelect="handleMenuItemPress"> 

        <u:MenuItem text="Camera" icon="sap-icon://add-photo" press="handleMenuItemPress"/>
        <u:MenuItem text="Gallery" icon="sap-icon://background" press="handleMenuItemPress"/>
        <u:MenuItem text="Display" visible="{= ${view>ImageData} !==''? true : false}" icon="sap-icon://show" press="handleMenuItemPress"/>
        <u:MenuItem text="{view>ImageData}"  icon="sap-icon://show" press="handleMenuItemPress"/>
        <u:MenuItem text="{view>Comments}"  icon="sap-icon://show" press="handleMenuItemPress"/>
    </u:Menu>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

The fragment is called in the controller like so.

```
handlePressOpenMenu: function (oEvent) {

        //Get Current Path
        var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
        var oAnswerSource = oButton.getBindingContext("view");
        var oAnswerPath = oAnswerSource.getPath();
        this.path = oAnswerPath;

        // create menu only once
        if (!this._menu) {
            this._menu = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "CompleteSurvey.view.fragments.Image",
                this
            );
            this._menu.bindElement(this.path);
            this.getView().addDependent(this._menu);
        }

        var eDock = sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock;
        this._menu.open(this._bKeyboard, oButton, eDock.BeginTop, eDock.BeginBottom, oButton);
    },
```

How do I get the bindingContext from the original view as I seem to have lost the context.

What do I need to setup in the controller + view?

Answer (score 2):

Solution was simple....

***this._menu.setBindingContext(oAnswerSource,"view");***

this.getView().addDependent(this._menu);